# How to print getter String without getting null as output?

Tags: java, class, object, methods, getter-setter

I get the null value whenever I use showMessage(); I believe that it is because
of me returning c at the end of the method. Are there any way to print out getName() without it being in main method, as in getName() being in the showMessage() method.                                                                           .
Here is my Candidate class

```
public class Candidate {

private String name;
private int votes;

//default constructor
public Candidate() {

String name = "Not Available! ";
int votes = 0; 
}

//overloaded constructor
public Candidate(String _name, int _votes){
  name  = _name;
  votes = _votes;

}

//getter
public String getName(){return name;}
public int getVotes(){return votes;}

//setter

public void incrementVote(){
  votes = votes + 1;

}

public void setName(String _name){
    name =_name;
}

public void print(){

    System.out.println("To vote for " + name);


}
}
```

Here is my main

```
import java.util.*;

public class Election {
public static void main(String args[]){

System.out.println("Welcome to the polls! ");

 Candidate c1 = new Candidate();
 Candidate c2 = new Candidate();
 Candidate c3 = new Candidate();
 Candidate c4 = new Candidate();


c1 = inputCandidate();
c2 = inputCandidate();
c3 = inputCandidate();
c4 = inputCandidate();



c1 = showMessage();

}

private static Candidate inputCandidate(){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String inputN;

    Candidate c = new Candidate();

    System.out.println("Enter candidate");

    inputN = sc.nextLine();
    c.setName(inputN);

   return c;
}

private static Candidate showMessage(){
    Candidate c = new Candidate();

    System.out.println(c.getName());

    return c;
}


}
```

Comment: showMessage printing null for the name is not possible. are you sure you re-compiled your code after altering it? or is it after that method that somewhere it prints null?

Comment: @Stultuske he does create a new Candidate object in showMessage() instead of using the ones he creates in the methods inputCandidate. So it should be very possible that it prints null as a name is never set in that new instance unless I'm missing something here.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS the name variable is set in the default constructor, so it shouldn't be possible [EDIT] scratch that, I missed that he set a local variable

Comment: Are you trying to show the name of `c1` or create a new Candidate and show the name of that newly created candidate?

Comment: @Matthew I am trying to show the name of c1, but it returns null all the time.

Comment: @mrtammy check DavidXXX's answer, that shows the issue in your current code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just replace

```
c1 = showMessage();
```

with,

```
showMessage(c1);
```

and modify  method `showMessage` like the following

```
private static void showMessage(Candidate c ){    

    System.out.println(c.getName());
}
```

so similarly,  you can use `showMessage` to print messages for remaining objects like

```
showMessage(c2);
showMessage(c3);
showMessage(c4);
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, putting class and object in method is really new to me, appreciate the guidance.

Comment: this changes the functionality, doesn't answer the question. his problem is the local variable in the default constructor, as Davidxxx mentioned

Comment: @Stultuske i understood that he is interested on `showMessage()`, as you can see what do you think `showMessage()` meant for? he is trying to print messages, i think he is not interested in initializing . he is already doing it that from input.

Comment: @mrtammy you are welcome, practice makes perfect. try to experiment what you read.

Answer (score 2):

try to pass the candidate inside the showMessage function as a parameter. Then inside the showMessage function use getName() to take the candidates name.
Check below :

```
import java.util.*;

public class Election {
    public static void main(String args[]){
    System.out.println("Welcome to the polls! ");

    Candidate c1 = new Candidate();
    Candidate c2 = new Candidate();
    Candidate c3 = new Candidate();
    Candidate c4 = new Candidate();


    c1 = inputCandidate();
    c2 = inputCandidate();
    c3 = inputCandidate();
    c4 = inputCandidate();



    showMessage(c1);

}

private static Candidate inputCandidate(){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String inputN;

    Candidate c = new Candidate();

    System.out.println("Enter candidate");

    inputN = sc.nextLine();
    c.setName(inputN);

    return c;
}

private static void showMessage(Candidate c){


    System.out.println(c.getName());

}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the constructor :

```
public Candidate() {    
  String name = "Not Available! ";
  int votes = 0; 
}
```

You value a local variable not the `name` instance field.
These refer two distinct objects.  So valuing the one doesn't have any effect on the other.
You committed the same mistake for the `votes` field but that doesn't cause any issue as an `int` field has `0` as default value.

So instead, set the `name` field :

```
public Candidate() {    
  this.name = "Not Available! ";
  // not required to set votes as it has 0 as default value
}
```

Or just use field initializers to give a default value to these fields :

```
public class Candidate {
   //...       
   private String name = "Not Available! ";    
   private int vote; //  0 as default value
   //...
}
```

Comment: Nice catch, missed that one.

Comment: @Stultuske Thanks :) But I didn't see right now the dead code for `votes`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

public Candidate() {

```
 this.name = "Not Available! ";// Previous code is creating a new temp variable by declaring it again, This implementation will set object variable not the temp variable

 this.votes = 0;
```

}